# Why Float.isNaN(Float.NaN) is "false" on an old LG phone Android 2.3.7?

Tags: android, nan

The following code seems to corrupt Float.isNaN() logic on an old Android device.
The device: LG-GT540 / Android2.3.7

[IMPORTANT UPDATE]
The Android on board is SwiftDroid v2.0 ASIS (Based on CyanogenMod-7.1.0)

```
int a = 2;
float b = a;
Log.d("yo", "1, Float.isNaN=" + Float.isNaN(Float.NaN));
boolean test = (b == 2);
Log.d("yo", "2, Float.isNaN=" + Float.isNaN(Float.NaN));
```

This makes Float.isNaN(Float.NaN) to return "false" which is wrong.

Do you know why?

Is it a JVM error?

On all the devices we own, the code runs as expected:

```
1, Float.isNaN=true
2, Float.isNaN=true
```

But on an old Android from LG the second NaN test fails.

```
1, Float.isNaN=true
2, Float.isNaN=false
```

But why?!

Any ideas to workaround this case are very welcome!

Comment: Thanks! Let's see what other guys have to say. Any idea on a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a comment of wiz3kid this is a bug.
Probably the error is related to modification SwiftDroid v2.0 ASIS (Based on CyanogenMod-7.1.0)